# how to view the data from page block table to input field?

Tags: apex, visualforce

i want to display the selected row value from the page block table to the input fields.
i have attached the screenshot of my UI [image]

My custom controller:

```
public class petwizardcontroller {
    public string ID_c {get;set;}
    public PCS_Household__c selected {get;set;}
    public List < PCS_Household__c > lstQuery {get;set;}
    public List < Pets_Information__c > character {get;set;}
    public List < string > Selection {get;set;}
    public string test {get;set;}
    public List < wpetwizardcontroller > chrcs {get;set;}
    public List < Characteristics__c > selctchr {get;set;}
    public petwizardcontroller() {
        lstQuery = new List < PCS_Household__c > ();
    }
    public List < wpetwizardcontroller > getchrc() {
        if (chrcs == null) {
            chrcs = new List < wpetwizardcontroller > ();
            for (Characteristics__c chrc: [SELECT ID, Good_with_Cats__c, Pet_ID__r.Gender__c, Pet_ID__r.Height__c, Pet_ID__r.Name__c, Pet_ID__r.pet__c, Pet_ID__r.Pet_Photo__c, Pet_ID__r.Status__c FROM Characteristics__c]) {
                chrcs.add(new wpetwizardcontroller(chrc));
            }
        }
        return chrcs;
    }
    public pageReference processSelectedFoos() {
        selctchr = new List < Characteristics__c > ();
        for (wpetwizardcontroller chrc: getchrc()) {
            if (chrc.selectd = true) {
                selctchr.add(chrc.chrc);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    public Void doSearch() {
        string Query = '';
        Query = 'SELECT ID,Name,Household__c,Phone__c,of_Childrens__c,of_Exiting_Pets__c,Address__c,Previous_Dog__c FROM PCS_Household__c where Household__c LIKE \'%' + ID_c + '%\'';
        system.debug('==Query==' + Query);
        lstQuery = Database.query(Query);
        system.debug('==lstQuery==' + lstQuery);
    }
    public pageReference doselected() {
        string slt = '';
        if ((ID_c != null && string.isNotBlank(ID_c))) {
            slt = 'SELECT Name,Household__c,Phone__c,of_Childrens__c,of_Exiting_Pets__c,Address__c,Previous_Dog__c FROM PCS_Household__c where ID =:test';
            system.debug('==Query==' + slt);
            selected = Database.query(slt);
            system.debug('==selected==' + selected);
        } else {
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR, 'Enter a value'));
        }
        return null;
    }

    public PageReference nextpage() {
        return Page.Screen2;
    }

    public class wpetwizardcontroller {
        public Characteristics__c chrc {get;set;}
        public boolean selectd {get;set;}
        //public Boolean Good_with_Cats {get; set;}
        //public Boolean HighNeed {get; set;}
        //public Boolean Non_shedder {get; set;}
        //public Boolean kid_friendly {get; set;}
        //public Boolean Predatory_Tendencies {get; set;}
        public wpetwizardcontroller(Characteristics__c chrc) {
            this.chrc = chrc;
            selectd = false;
            //Good_with_Cats=false;
            //HighNeed=false;
            //Non_shedder=false;
            //kid_friendly=false;
            //Predatory_Tendencies=false;
        }
    }
}
```

visual force page:

```
<apex:page controller="petwizardcontroller" sidebar="false" wizard="false" >


<apex:outputPanel id="msg">
<apex:pageMessages ></apex:pageMessages>
</apex:outputPanel>

<apex:form >        
    Household Name: <apex:inputText value="{!ID_c}" />
    <apex:commandButton value="Search" action="{!doSearch}" rerender="pblck,msg"/>

<apex:pageBlock id="pblck" >
    <apex:pageblockTable value="{!lstQuery}" var="eachRecord" >
        <apex:column > <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" action="{!doclick}" rerender="out" >
            <!--<apex:param value="{!eachRecord.ID}" assignTo="{!test}"/>-->
        </apex:actionSupport></apex:column>
        <apex:column value="{!eachRecord.Household__c}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!eachRecord['Name']}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!eachRecord.Phone__c}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!eachRecord.of_Childrens__c}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!eachRecord.of_Exiting_Pets__c}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!eachRecord.Address__c}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!eachRecord.Previous_Dog__c}"/>
    </apex:pageblockTable>
   </apex:pageBlock>

    <apex:commandButton value="None of These" action="{!doselected}" rerender="msg,out"/>
```

```
    <apex:inputField value="{!selected.Household__c}"></apex:inputField> 
    <apex:inputField value="{!selected.Phone__c}"></apex:inputField>              
    <apex:inputField value="{!selected.of_Childrens__c}"></apex:inputField>
    <apex:inputField value="{!selected.of_Exiting_Pets__c}"></apex:inputField>
    <apex:inputField value="{!selected.Address__c}"></apex:inputField>
    <apex:inputField value="{!selected.Previous_Dog__c}"></apex:inputField>
   </apex:pageBlockSection>
   <apex:commandButton value="Next" action="{!nextpage}"/>
  </apex:pageBlock>
```

help me.
thanks in advance.

Comment: you have any checkbox or something to select a row from pageBlockTable? Post your custom controller also.

Comment: no rohit .without checkbox i have to do..

Comment: Could you also post the VF code?

Comment: i have added the both..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the visualforce `repeat` function to make a list out of those rows, and just turn off the display of the undesired rows. Using JavaScript/jQuery, when you click a row in the table above, you would change the `display` attribute of the respective fields in the second table to `block`, while setting `none` to the rest of the fields (that are fields for different rows, so you don't want to display those).

This is simple for tables that won't load too many rows. If you have a really large amount of data (think 1k+), then I wouldn't take this suggestion.

Comment: i want to view only one row in the input field